# Access variable in different function PHP

Tags: php, arrays, class

I'm trying to access 3 variables from 3 different functions in a single function. They're all arrays. I want to `foreach` them in that single function.

```
class poetry {
    public function __construct() {
        add_action( 'wp_head', array( $this, 'generate_scripts' ) );
    }

    public function page_one() {
        $options = array(
            array( 'content1', 'Content1', 'The Content 1'),
            array( 'content2', 'Content2', 'The Content 2'),
            array( 'content3', 'Content3', 'The Content 3'),
        );

        $this->add_settings( 'page_one', $options );
    }

    public function page_two() {
        $options = array(
            array( 'content4', 'Content4', 'The Content 4'),
            array( 'content5', 'Content5', 'The Content 5'),
            array( 'content6', 'Content6', 'The Content 6'),
        );

        $this->add_settings( 'page_two', $options );
    }

    public function page_three() {
        $options = array(
            array( 'content7', 'Content7', 'The Content 7'),
            array( 'content8', 'Content8', 'The Content 8'),
            array( 'content9', 'Content9', 'The Content 9'),
        );

        $this->add_settings( 'page_three', $options );
    }

    public function generate_scripts() {
        // how do I access $options from the above functions in this function?
        foreach($options as $option) {
            echo $option[0];
        }
    }

}
```

How can I access all 3 `$options` from the above functions and foreach the arrays in `generate_scripts()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the variables within the same *scope* as the function you want to use them in. You can either set variables of the class using `$this`, or you can `return` the array. Either way, you need to call it first.

Here's an example on how you can create them all variables as properties of the class, and using `$this`. Note that you need to call the method to populate the variable before you can use it.

```
class poetry {
    private $page_one; // Initialize variable first

    public function __construct() {
        add_action( 'wp_head', array( $this, 'generate_scripts' ) );
    }

    public function page_one() {
        $this->page_one = array(
            array( 'content1', 'Content1', 'The Content 1'),
            array( 'content2', 'Content2', 'The Content 2'),
            array( 'content3', 'Content3', 'The Content 3'),
        );
    }

    /* Rest of class */

   public function generate_scripts() {
        $this->page_one(); // Call method, so variable holds the values
        $options = $this->page_one;
        foreach($options as $option) {
            echo $option[0];
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can use `return` each array, and use that as the `$options` value. If you need to use it multiple times inside the function, you can `return $options;` at the end - after doing everything you need. This way, the method returns the array - and you can use it as a variable inside as much as you need!

```
public function page_one() {
    $options = array(
        array( 'content1', 'Content1', 'The Content 1'),
        array( 'content2', 'Content2', 'The Content 2'),
        array( 'content3', 'Content3', 'The Content 3'),
    );

    $this->add_settings( 'page_one', $options );
    return $options;
}


public function generate_scripts() {
    $options = $this->page_one();
    foreach($options as $option) {
        echo $option[0];
    }
}
```

If you want all methods to be called, you need to add additional code. You could have a property of the class where you push all the arrays as the methods are called, and loop that - but you will still need to call those methods to populate the variable before being able to use it.

Comment: Let me know if I can help! What exactly are you trying to figure out?

Comment: Oh, there was a WordPress function giving a undefined error. Fixed it by placing the return above it instead of under it. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php

class poetry {

    private $options_one;
    private $options_two;
    private $options_three;


    public function __construct() {
        add_action('wp_head', array($this, 'generate_scripts'));
    }

    public function page_one() {
        global $options_one;
        $options_one = array(
            array('content1', 'Content1', 'The Content 1'),
            array('content2', 'Content2', 'The Content 2'),
            array('content3', 'Content3', 'The Content 3'),
        );
    }

    public function page_two() {
        global $options_two;
        $options_two = array(
            array('content4', 'Content4', 'The Content 4'),
            array('content5', 'Content5', 'The Content 5'),
            array('content6', 'Content6', 'The Content 6'),
        );
    }

    public function page_three() {
        global $options_three;
        $options_three = array(
            array('content7', 'Content7', 'The Content 7'),
            array('content8', 'Content8', 'The Content 8'),
            array('content9', 'Content9', 'The Content 9'),
        );
    }

    public function generate_scripts() {
        $this->page_one();
        $this->page_two();
        $this->page_three();
        global $options_one, $options_two, $options_three;
        $options = array_merge($options_one[0], $options_two[0], $options_three[0]);
        foreach ($options as $option) {
            echo $option . "<br/>";
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: No explanation, and just a code-dump. It's not going to be much helpful. Besides, usage of `global` isn't a good idea to begin with..

Comment: Well it is not code dump. I modified it by self, and if your code is good enough you do not need an explanation.

Comment: That is exactly what it is, a code-dump! There's no text to explain or support it. So you need to study each line to see what changed you made, which isn't a good answer. [How to write a good answer (SO meta)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7656/how-do-i-write-a-good-answer-to-a-question). And even so, the approach with having `global` really isn't a good idea, [why you shouldn't use `global`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1558073/4535200). And if you're going to downvote my answer too, at least write a comment *why* ;-)